# check Relationship table on model, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have project with ruby on rails 3.2.14. i have 2 table named "countries" and "users". in "users" table have FK named "countries_id".
on model i have make table relation like:
in `countries.rb` i have set relationship like:

```
class Countries < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "id"
  has_many  :users,  :dependent => :destroy # plural
end
```

and in users.rb like:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "id"


  belongs_to    :countries,
                :class_name => "Countries",
                :foreign_key => "countries_id"

end
```

and when i want to check plural relationship, it's didn't.. 
i type in rails console command like below

```
c=Countries.find_by_id(1)
```

and then when i type command  `u=c.users` , i have some error
the error:

```
c=Countries.find_by_id(1)
  Countries Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Countries id: 1, code: "IND", name: "Indonesia", created_at: "2014-02-17 09:18:11", updated_at: "2014-02-17 09:18:11"> 
1.9.3-p484 :012 > u=c.users
NameError: uninitialized constant Countries::User
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:118:in `klass'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:171:in `find_target?'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:334:in `load_target'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:44:in `load_target'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/vinra/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.2/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p484 :013 > ^C
1.9.3-p484 :013 >
```

i really hopping somebody knowing my problem, 
anyway thank you,, sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Please follow rails naming convention model name should not be plural

Comment: what do you mean,, can more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change a lot of things in your code:

**app/models/country.rb**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :country,
               :foreign_key => "countries_id"
end
```

And use it like this:

```
country = Country.find(1)
p country.users
```

Comment: why i must use class name "Country" i have create g model with name countries and in database my table named countries too,, 
what is different? anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: All models in rails should be Singular. So you would need to rename your tables, too.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that Rails `Active Record` Models cant be **Plural**. You created the models with plural,so change them to singular or better way is to create them again with singular names.

`Countries` should be `Country` and `Users` should be `User`.

For more information on Naming Conventions,see [This](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer, must i have to rebuild my project from beginning ? or i can edit name table and model from migration  ?

Comment: First try editing your model names to singular and check.If it is not working then you must create them again with the singular names.